# Color preview for AS3 in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, ide

Is there a color preview for ActionScript 3 files in IntelliJ IDEA? 
If not, which IDE provides it?

PS: I can enable it for CSS files:

[image]

PPS: I am working in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), which you should for AS3 development anyway, there's an insert color option from the menu.

[image]